# CSS Hover and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, hover, onmouseover

I have menu item in html with following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hzHJj/

When you move your mouse over `div#heli` or `div#reflection_heli` I need it to shift `div#heli` up and `div#heli_reflection` down at the same time. I managed to make it shift only one of the div at time or 2 divs excatly the same way.

Comment: Please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Do you have a javascript code?

Comment: I know it's valid HTML(5) but wrapping a div in anchor just still seems so wrong..

Comment: Right now we don't have any other javascript code.

Comment: Moved code to jsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a wrapper element, your existing li is good. And when it's in hover state (`li:hover`) make the changes for #heli and #heli_reflection

http://jsfiddle.net/sJYWr/